# Toilet Paper Math?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, rebus

**Ben** stared in dismay at the hundreds of bits of **paper** scattered around his room.  This was going to be a lot of work.
His brother waltzed in and picked up a larger **sheet**.
"Watchya doin' writin' about toilet paper?" he asked.
"It's not about toilet paper," replied Ben.  "It's a puzzle."

Primary puzzle goal: identify the mechanism.
Secondary puzzle goal: complete the following equations by filling in the missing digits.
For the second part (digits), there is an intended/best solution, but other interesting solutions are accepted, as the "math" is not precise.  (Personally I only found one good solution for each, but leaving this disclaimer just in case).

- 5122 + 4454 = 4470
- 4847 + 1241 = 2440
- 4192 + 5077 + 4735 = 3912
- 740 + 2475 = 2280
- 614 + 548 + 4550 = 233
- 1562 + 4437 = 4???
- 1932 + 2938 = 2???
- 2404 + 73 = 2???
- 1504 + 5032 = ???

Hint 1:

> [image: Dilbert]

Hint 2:

> It is perfectly normal for this situation to occur. *My* room is also sometimes covered in tiny bits of paper. Why? And why is his name Ben?

Hint 3:

> Ben is number one.   He is also an American.

Hint 4:

> [Oh](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112147/what-a-tangled-web-we-weave)

Hint 5:

> The key to solving this puzzle hinges upon a single word. The word is hidden in some fairly obvious places, though it itself is not so obvious. The word is NOT Ben, Sheet, Paper, or any other word in this puzzle; neither does it contain an 'A'.

Hint 6:

> The topic is clued by the body and Hint 2. It is simple and well known by everyone, not nearly as esoteric as the two suggestions given in comments.
>  If you find the topic, you will immediately find yourself looking for something else, something very specific and "mathematical". For that, look to the title (or any or all of the other hints; they are redundant). The title is less useful for non-Americans, thus I offered some alternate hints.

Hint 7:

> Topic: You wouldn't lick toilet paper, but...
>  Enumeration: The title refers to a specific American brand name

Comment: Just want to see if I'm on the right track.. rot13(qbrf guvf unf gb qb jvgu Ze S naq uvf ZF'f. Vs vg vf, lbh'yy trg vg. Vs vg'f abg arire zvaq)

Comment: @prim3numbah rot13: V guvax V xabj jub lbh zrna, naq ur vf snzbhf sbe n ybg bs *bgure* guvatf. Fb unys evtug.

Comment: Disclaimer to puzzlers: Unless you are one of the minority of people familiar with this topic, I fully expect and am okay with you using google sleuthing to find the answer, in combination with some deduction. If google sleuthing is not your cup of tea, check out my other puzzles which are more accessible based on common knowledge.

Comment: rot13(
Qbrf vg unir nalguvat gb qb jvgu guvf fvghngvba?

uggcf://jjj.aru.tbi/negvpyr/orawnzva-senaxyva-naq-cnzcuyrg-jnef) ?

Comment: Evtug crefba, jebat gbcvp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mechanism is

> to combine elements, words, or ideas, of postage stamps by their Scott Catalogue number.

5122 + 4454 = 4470

> Cat + Dog = Garfield and Odie

4847 + 1241 = 2440

> Heart + Birds = Birds on Heart

4192 + 5077 + 4735 = 3912

> Mickey Mouse + (planet) Pluto + Cake = Mickey, Pluto, and Cake

740 + 2475 = 2280

> Yosemite + Flag = Flag over Yosemite

614 + 548 + 4550 = 233

> Ship + Ship + Ship = Fleet of Columbus

1562 + 4437 = 4???

> = 4193
>  Peter (Francisco) + (Liberty) Bell = Peter (Pan) and (Tinker) Bell
> It definitely helped (good puzzle design) that the first stamp we had to come up with on our own was one that we had already seen in the same sheet as Mickey in a previous equation.

1932 + 2938 = 2???

> = 2046
>  Babe (Zaharias) + Ruth (Benedict) = Babe Ruth (the Sultan of Swat, the King of Krash, the Colossus of Clout, the Colossus of Clout, the Great Bambino)

2404 + 73 = 2???

> = 2592
>  Washington (state) + Andrew Jackson = George Washington and Andrew Jackson

1504 + 5032 = ???

> = 292
>  Rural America with Angus Cattle + Blue Geometric Snowflake = Cattle in Snowstorm

The hint "Ben is number one. He is also an American."

> Benjamin Franklin fought against the Stamp Act and appeared on the first American postage stamp.

"Toilet Paper Math", Dilbert, and "What a tangled web we weave" hint at

> Scott toilet paper brand, Scott Adams, and Sir Walter Scott, which all lead us to the Scott Catalogue

Comment: This is a good start! Solving the 4192 line may help with part 2 (filling in the blanks) as there is a slight complicating factor in some of the equations. If you get stuck, you can always consult a mystic.

Comment: Excellent work! The last one is considered by many to be one of the finest U.S. stamps ever made. If it's not found in a week I'll add in the answer.

Comment: Is the last one Onor gur oyhr bk by any chance?