# Cracking the Cryptic Logo

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, graph-theory

The well-known [Cracking The Cryptic YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/CrackingTheCryptic) has a logo consisting of 12 circles joined by 16 straight lines running horizontally, vertically or diagonally.

- What is the significance of this logo?
- When you’ve answered this question, you know what to do next

NOTE: I did not invent this puzzle. This is rather a fun fact I stumbled upon while watching a recent video. I had to share it

[image: Cracking the Cryptic logo]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not being a follower of this particular YouTube channel, this is new to me. However, it strongly reminds me of [another puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/112147/60644) seen on Puzzling earlier this year, which I believe has a similar mechanism at heart... In which case, the answer is that:

> the logo represents a **network of letters**, which when placed correctly enable you to spell out the words 'CRACKING THE CRYPTIC' by tracing a path through them, starting and ending at the 'C':
>
>  [image: Network of letters]
>
>  Very pleasing!

Comment: Jryy qbar. V qvqa'g xabj bs guvf bgure chmmyr, ohg vzzrqvngryl gubhtug 'jr arrq gb svaq n cngu va gung tencu' orpnhfr bayl gjb iregvprf unir na bqq qrterr (P naq E va lbhe fbyhgvba)

Comment: @Stef That's a good observation and would form a great base to start from with no other knowledge at all :)

Comment: that other puzzle reference by Stiv is *so* cool! :-)